# Show that a solution is linear and find its matrix in the usual basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

On $\mathbb{R}^3$, define $$A(x) = (x \cdot a)a + 2(x \cdot b)b$$  Here $$a = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}, b = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Show that A is linear and find its matrix in the usual basis.

I did out the above equation and got $A(x) = (x*a \cdot a^2) + 2(x*b + b^2)$.  This reduces to $0+2x$.

I understand that the usual basis means that $$e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, e_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Did I do the matrix algebra incorrectly or is the answer the actually $2x$?  If so, $2x$ is linear, but you cannot reduce that to a basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\ y\\ z\end{array}\right)=(x-z)\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\ 0\\ -1\end{array}\right)+2y\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}x-z\\ 2y\\ -x+z\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}1 & 0 & -1\\ 0& 2& 0\\ -1& 0& 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\ y\\ z\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Ah.  I see.  I took the $x$ in $A(x)$ too literally.  In $\mathbb{R}^3$, it is $(x,y,z)$.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You're welcome.

Comment: Isn't the matrix on the right not a basis?  It is linearly dependant.

Comment: The rank of the matrix, as you say, is not three. It has rank two. This means that the associated linear map has a non-trivial kernel. But it is the matrix that defines the linear transformation with respect to the usual basis $e_1,e_2,e_3.$ Note that a matrix associated to a linear map doesn't have to be of maximum rank. Think of the map that sends any vector to zero.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really understanding what you wrote there.  I understand that the matrix is of rank 2.  Does "find its matrix in the usual basis" mean to find the matrix that, when multiplied by the solution that we found to A, is equal to the usual basis?  How do you prove that A is linear?

Comment: Find the matrix in the usual basis means to find the matrix that sends the vector $xe_1+ye_2+ze_3$ to a vector written in the same basis. In our case to the vector $(x-z)e_1+2ye_2+(-x+z)e_3.$ To show linearity you need to show that $A(\lambda \vec{x}+\mu \vec{y})=\lambda A(\vec{x})+\mu A(\vec{y}),$ where $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in \mathbb{R}^3.$

Comment: Isn't $(x-z)e_1+2ye_2+(-x+z)e_3$ just $A*(e_1,e_2,e_3)$?  Meaning that the matrix in the usual basis is just A?  Or is it $\left(\begin{array}{rrr}x-z & 0 & 0\\ 0& 2y& 0\\ 0& 0& -x+z\end{array}\right)$

Comment: Note that the first column of the matrix must be $Ae_1=\left(\begin{array}{r}1 \\ 0\\ -1\end{array}\right),$ the second $Ae_2=\left(\begin{array}{r}0 \\ 2\\ 0\end{array}\right),$ and the third one $Ae_3=\left(\begin{array}{r}-1 \\ 0\\ 1\end{array}\right).$ Note that the matrix only contain numbers and not letters, as in your last matrix.

Comment: Sorry, now I'm even more confused.  The straight multiplication that you did makes sense (i.e. $A*\left(\begin{array}{r}1 \\ 0\\ 0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{r}1 \\ 0\\ -1\end{array}\right)$).  This just makes me think that the answer is the same as the matrix A that we found above.

Comment: Yes, the matrix is $\left(\begin{array}{rrr}1 & 0 & -1\\ 0& 2& 0\\ -1& 0& 1\end{array}\right).$